# Jquery Datatable - Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

This already works:

- Spring MVC Controller for retrieving the model and the data for my table.
- Displaying the data in a table with Jquery datatable.

Here is the significant Controller Code

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("mymodel")
public class MyController {
....
@ModelAttribute("mymodel") //The model is just for search criterias
public MyModell addModell() {
   ...
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/myStartPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String myStartPage(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
....
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/dataTable", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody String dataTable(HttpServletRequest  request, @ModelAttribute("mymodel") MyModell modell, BindingResult result) throws IOException {
.... //this code is called from the datatable via ajax
}
```

Here is the significant JSP Code

```
<!-- Many Input Fields for Search Criteria -->
...
<div class="col-sm-2  col">
   Search-Criteria xyzNumber
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2 col3">
        <input type="text">
</div>
...

<!-- The datatable Code-->
var table = $('#myHtmlTable').DataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sort": "position",
        "bStateSave": false,
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        "iDisplayStart": 0,
        "sAjaxSource": "dataTable",
        "sAjaxDataProp": "data",
        "orderClasses": false,
      ...
```

If the page is shown the table is displayed. Now the user should enter data in the input fields and then i want to refresh the table. But how could i get the data from the input fields to my dataTable method. I want to transfer all input data to the my dataTable method.

Comment: best option is that you save those input data to the DB and by ajax reload the table data.

Comment: ? I think you misunderstood my problem....

Comment: maybe...I understood you need to save some user input and show in your table, right? but maybe you want to allow the user type directly in the table?

Comment: no.... i don't want to save user input. The user shoul specifiy some "Search-Criterias" and then the table should be reloaded by this criterias limited result set.

Comment: Yeah I have understood what you want to do. I have done the same thing using jQuery AJAX.

Comment: @MehmoodMemon and do you use the datatable plugin? if yes a little example would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the forums:
[https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/2456/datatables-spring-mvc-support]

Comment: I know this link. But this doesn't help me. Unfortunately i didn't found anything on the web.....

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you use this: [datatables.net](https://datatables.net/)

To **refresh** (redraw) the dataTables **without page reload** you just need:

```
table.clear().draw();
table.rows.add(data); // Add new data
table.columns.adjust().draw(); // Redraw the DataTable
```

Comment: this was not my question.

Comment: You previously wrote: _The user should specifiy some "Search-Criterias" and then the table should be reloaded by this criterias limited result set._
Yuo just need take data form input, send to the server, receive new data and redraw table, yes?